# union of infinitely many bounded sets is not bounded

Tags: analysis

Why is a union of infinitely many bounded sets not necessarily bounded, please? In addition, what condition can we add to make this union bounded, please?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a bounded set (say, on the real line)? Can you see why a union of infinitely many of them might not be bounded?

Comment: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [-n, n] = (-\infty, +\infty).$$

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{R}^n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\left\|x\right|\leq n\}$

A finite union of bounded sets is bounded.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Each subset of a metric space is a union of bounded sets (the singletons) but not every subset is bounded.

Comment: Such a clever argument.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking why it's not *necessarily* true that such a union is bounded, it suffices to consider a counterexample. Define $A_n = [n, n + 1]$; then

$$\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} A_n = [0, \infty)$$

is unbounded.

It is necessary and sufficient that there is a common bound on all the $A_n$ for the union of the $A_n$ to be bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your response.